# Change background color with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to change multiple div backgrounds with a click in button using JavaScript button :

**JS :**

```
function button_click(color) {
     document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = color;
     document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

**CSS :**

```
div#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}

div#box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="box">Hey there</div>
<div id="box1">Hey there</div>
<button type="button" onclick="button_click('red');">Switch</button>
```

> Oh and I would like to use this button to change the background colors
>   of 4 div's, hide and unhide 3 div's and maybe some other junk 
>   This is just a snippet of code from my actuall project and with my actual 
>   project I am using Bootstrap but I don't know if it has anything that could 
>   help me with this particular case

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I will downvote you purely off principle, you won't up vote a good answer because I quote "I'd upvote your answer if this website didn't take away my points for asking this question." You should Up Vote good answers regardless of how bad your question is.

Comment: No I was saying I literally can not upvote the website wouldn't let me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an identifier to your button who should change color , e.g :

```
<button type="button" id="change-color">Switch colors</button>
```

And give the divs you want to change a global `class` and use `data` attribute to specify `color` e.g :

```
<div id="box" class='color-div' data-color='red'>Hey there red</div>
<div id="box1" class='color-div' data-color='green'>Hey there green</div>
<div id="box2" class='color-div' data-color='blue'>Hey there blue</div>
```

And assign `click` event to the button that will go through all the divs and give every one specified color in data :

```
$('body').on('click', '.change-color', function(){
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    $('.global-class-'+color).css('background-color', color);
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$('body').on('click', '#change-color', function(){
    $('.color-div').each(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('color'));
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="change-color">Switch colors</button>

<div id="box" class='color-div' data-color='red'>Hey there red</div>
<div id="box1" class='color-div' data-color='green'>Hey there green</div>
<div id="box2" class='color-div' data-color='blue'>Hey there blue</div>
```

Comment: But what if I want all of the div's to be their own individual colors? Also thank you for your help so far. I'd upvote your answer if this website didn't take away my points for asking this question.

Comment: You're welcome bro check my update, (the users who take of your points and not website) anyway +1 from me, but consider to add specific question in you OP.

Comment: Ok sry about that I'm just new to too this site so I'm still figuring it out. Thanks for input though :D

Comment: Sorry about asking another question but you seem knowlegable about what if I wanted all those divs to be changed to different colors but only using one button to change all those different things

Comment: :) now you have points, ok i'll provide another update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99425/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-cosmichero-2025).